# How do I best access the value attribute of the DOM-Element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have dynamically generated the following dropdown list using jquery for the calculator app I am currently making:

```
<select type="text" id="field__left">
   <option label="Please choose an unit!" text="Please choose an unit!"></option>
   <option label="inch" text="Inch" value="0.0254"></option>
   <option label="foot" text="Foot" value="0.3048"></option>
   <option label="yard" text="Yard" value="0.9144"></option>
   <option label="rod" text="Rod" value="5.0292"></option>
   <option label="chain" text="Chain" value="20.1168"></option>
   <option label="furlong" text="Furlong" value="201.168"></option>
   <option label="mile" text="Mile" value="1609.344"></option>
   <option label="cable" text="Cable" value="185.2"></option>
   <option label="nautical mile" text="Nautical mile" value="1852"></option>
   <option label="shipday" text="Shipday" value="185200"></option>
</select>
```

What now I try is to access the value attribute of every option, but I don't get far. The examiner is showing the value attribute in the elements tab, I can also find under the options when I look at the properties in the browser, but I am unable to access them via JavaScript.

I tried:

```
const leftVal = $('#field__left').children('option').attr('value');
```

also

```
const leftVal = $('#field__left').children('option').data('value');
```

but it returned undefined, while:

```
const leftVal = document.querySelector('#field__left').getAttribute('value');
```

gave me null.

Anybody has the ide where my mistake lies?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try is to access the value attribute of every option

You need a loop...

```js
$("#field__left option").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="text" id="field__left">
   <option label="Please choose an unit!" text="Please choose an unit!"></option>
   <option label="inch" text="Inch" value="0.0254"></option>
   <option label="foot" text="Foot" value="0.3048"></option>
   <option label="yard" text="Yard" value="0.9144"></option>
   <option label="rod" text="Rod" value="5.0292"></option>
   <option label="chain" text="Chain" value="20.1168"></option>
   <option label="furlong" text="Furlong" value="201.168"></option>
   <option label="mile" text="Mile" value="1609.344"></option>
   <option label="cable" text="Cable" value="185.2"></option>
   <option label="nautical mile" text="Nautical mile" value="1852"></option>
   <option label="shipday" text="Shipday" value="185200"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#field__left').children('option')` will return an array of all select option nodes, you have to iterate through it to get values of each option

Here is the simple solution

```
// get list of an options
var options = $('#field__left option');

// Then, convert that into an array of just the values
var values = $.map(options, e => $(e).val())

console.log(values)
```

Comment: Thank you both.

At last, I simply went for

const firstVal = (leftInput.val() *1);

because it always returns the value of the option selected which is needed for further calculation.